# CMS to implement custom design but editable text, images

Tags: web-apps, cms

I need a CMS (preferably written in Python), which allows me as a developer to build a custom specific design, but allows the client (not a technical person) to edit text, images, font sizes, colors etc.

Until now, we have been using Drupal, and the client needed to edit HTML code to be able to edit text, however since he's not a technical person, I need to somehow be able to add tokens in the code, which can be edited from a user-friendly page. Are there CMS platforms that support this?

Comment: What do you mean by "token"?

Comment: Placeholders which get replaced with text entered from some kind of admin panel.